# Importing cvs file with coordinates into QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, csv, import

I got a problem. I got some coordinates in Excel. They are written with comma `14459091,1010` ex.

When I try to import them as `csv`-file into QGIS, it will only create a table and no points. When I look in the properties it says that my `"x"` and `"y"` columns are strings.

I use a semicolon to separate the fields.

Comment: Follow this guide https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7 to separate the column that contains your x and y to 2 columns. Then use the import csv in QGIS and choose each column for your x and y.

Comment: Or set two signs (semikolon & comma) as separators.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I got two colums already . One with x coordinates and one with y. Ex X 29494,449 and Y 020204,919.

Comment: Check the box "use comma as decimal separator" and also choose your delimiter u use

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I didn't check the box for "use comma as decimal separator" a